# How to run the loop and return into different lists everytime in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data as follows

```
     Gene  Distance
0    A       18
1    B       16
2    C       58
3    D       45
4    E       34
```

If two genes have distance less than 50, they should be combined (in a list) as follows

```
1 A,B
2 C,D,E
```

A loop should bread between B and C as the distance between them is more than 50. How can I create such breaks in a loop and for lists many times.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. We can guide you from there.

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: Yes, I am using Pandas Dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `groupby` (should be faster than loop ..)

```
df.Gene.groupby(df.Distance.gt(50).cumsum()).apply(list).str.join(',')
Out[347]: 
Distance
0      A,B
1    C,D,E
Name: Gene, dtype: object
```